# how to avoid loops when using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ufunc

I have an numpy array with size of 10x250000 and I need to change values of it during the program but using "for loop" make my program very slow. it is the mentioned section of program. (L2 , L1 and T are other arrays) :

```
EEf1=numpy.zeros((10,250000))
for m in range(10):
          for n in range(250000):
                    EEf1[m,n]+=2*(L2[m,0]-T[m,0])*L2[m,0]*(1-L2[m,0])*L1[n,0]
```

My question : Is there any solution to use numpy features to avoid this loop ?
I have tried **fromfunction** method like this (for example):

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i,j : A[i,j]+B[i,j] , (2,2))
```

(A and B are 2x2 arrays)
but it doesnt work.
I really need to avoid this loop.
can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), but it's difficult to test without a reproducible example:

```
EEf1 = 2*(L2[:, 0] - T[:, 0]) * L2[:, 0] * (1 - L2[:, 0]) * L1[None, :, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time there is little change to do, just skip the for loops.

Here you have a shape mismatch between `L1` and `L2` -- [`np.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) does the job here:

```py
def my_func(L1, L2, T):
    return np.outer(2 * (L2 - T) * L2 * (1 - L2), L1)
```

Also, it is a bit odd that `L1`, `L2` and `T` are not 1D arrays to begin with, because you only ever use their first column.

Equality check:

```py
M, N = 10, 25_000
L1 = np.random.rand(N, 1)
L2 = np.random.rand(M, 1)
T = np.random.rand(M, 1)

expected = op_func(L1, L2, T)
result = my_func(L1, L2, T)

np.array_equal(result, expected)  # True
```

Performance tests:

```py
>>> %timeit op_func(L1, L2, T)
... %timeit my_func(L1, L2, T)

250 ms ± 2.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
85.2 µs ± 191 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Your lines of code as a function, for reference:

```py
def op_func(L1, L2, T):
    N, M = L1.shape[0], L2.shape[0]
    assert T.shape[0] == M
    EEf1 = np.zeros((M, N))
    for m in range(M):
        for n in range(N):
            EEf1[m, n] += (
                2 * (L2[m, 0] - T[m, 0]) * L2[m, 0] * (1 - L2[m, 0]) * L1[n, 0]
            )
    return EEf1
```